# Нужны ли плагины Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, wordpress-плагины

Хотелось бы узнать можно ли при создании сайта и его насадки на Wordpress обойтись без плагинов, так как многие нужные функции присутствуют только в pro версиях которые стоят достаточно дорого, а к примеру самому сверстать все слайдеры или галереи?

Comment: Все можно. Вопрос, сколько у вас времени займёт повторение функционала, существующего хотя бы в бесплатных версиях плагинов.

Comment: "насадки на Wordpress"... повбвавбы.. Создание сайта на  Wordpress!!!. А по вопросу см https://wpmag.ru/2014/functions-php/